# Delphi XE2 styles painting

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

I am having trouble with incorrectly painted corners when drawing VCL-styled window elements. On styles that have rounded corners, I get a white background in the space between the control's bounding rect and the style's rounded window corner.

[image]

The above image was run using Aqua Light Slate, but any style with rounded corners will show this same problem. What am I missing?

```delphi
type
  TSample = class(TCustomControl)
  protected
    procedure Paint; override;
  end;

{ TForm1 }
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  R: TRect;
  S: TSample;
begin
  R := ClientRect;
  InflateRect(R, -20, -20);
  S := TSample.Create(Application);
  S.Parent := Self;
  S.BoundsRect := R;
end;

{ TSample }
procedure TSample.Paint;
var
  Details: TThemedElementDetails;
begin
  Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(twCaptionActive);
  StyleServices.DrawParentBackground(Self.Handle, Canvas.Handle, Details, False);
  StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, ClientRect);
end;
```

Comment: btw, I also tried ParentBackground := True, no change. Have also tried making sure csOpaque is removed.

Comment: Are you tried debugging the `StyleServices.DrawElement` method to see how it draw the bitmap in the canvas?

Comment: Frankly I was hoping to avoid diving into the internals of the theme engine, but if no one has any better ideas, that's what I'll have to do.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't help. DrawElement is drawing white corners whether the DC is the offscreen bitmap, or the control's canvas. I proved this by filling the offscreen bitmap with a solid color first, then calling DrawElement into the bitmap, but using a rectangle not as wide as the bitmap and centered. The result was my solid color on both sides, and the caption bar in the middle, still with white corners. DrawElement is just not drawing the corners transparent, for some reason.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, I spend some minutes in you question and I found the answer. The key to draw the rounded corners, is call the [`StyleServices.GetElementRegion`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Themes.TCustomStyleServices.GetElementRegion) function to get the region and then use the [`SetWindowRgn`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd145102%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to apply the region to the control.

check this sample

```
procedure TSample.Paint;
var
  Details : TThemedElementDetails;
  Region  : HRgn;
  LRect   : TRect;
begin
  Details := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(twCaptionActive);
  LRect := Rect(0, 0, Width, Height);
  StyleServices.GetElementRegion(Details, LRect, Region);
  SetWindowRgn(Handle, Region, True);
  StyleServices.DrawParentBackground(Self.Handle, Canvas.Handle, Details, False);
  StyleServices.DrawElement(Canvas.Handle, Details, ClientRect);
end;
```

And this is the result

[image]

Comment: This absolutely works, thanks so much for the help! This also works with using an offscreen bitmap for the caption area. For anyone else doing something similar, it's worth pointing out that the entire client rect needs to be passed to GetElementRegion.