# Get Backgroundcolor of themed TListView

Tags: delphi, listview, themes, background-color

Since XE2, there are several themes that can be used for your application. E.g. *Carbon* that changes the background color of the TListView to *gray* besides other things.

Is there any way to get this color?
TListView.Color returns *white* altough the background is some kind of *gray*.

I tried using StyleServices.GetElementDetails with a snippet like this:

```
     var   lColor: TColor;
           lDetails: TThemedElementDetails;

     if StyleServices.Enabled then
     begin
        lDetails := StyleServices.GetElementDetails(tlListviewRoot);
        StyleServices.GetElementColor(lDetails, ecFillColor, lColor);
     end;
```

But `GetElementColor`fails and returns *false*. Am I using the wrong parameter? Or is my approach just wrong.

The possible parameters can be found here:
[TThemedListView](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE3/de/Vcl.Themes.TThemedListview)
[TElementColor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/de/Vcl.Themes.TElementColor)

Thank you.

P.S.: I also read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10094396/delphi-xe2-styles-painting) but the answer didn't help me so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the background color of the TListView that has a StyleHook implemented :

```
uses Vcl.Themes;

var Color : TColor; 
Color := StyleServices.GetStyleColor(scListView);
```

Comment: thank you! this seems to work. will do some more checks and accept soon